# How do I correct Vim spelling mistakes quicker?

Tags: vim, spell-checking

My usual Vim work flow is:

- In insert mode, spell something wrong.

  [image: Vim spell]
- Press `^X s` to get some suggestions.

  [image: Vim screen]
- Press Esc to accept the first one.

After this, I'm in command mode in the middle of the line, instead of insert mode of where I was before. I could use `A`, but that only works if I was typing on the end of the line. Is there an alternative way? Optimally, I'd like a command that corrects the last mistake to the first suggestion without moving the cursor.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

This works fairly well:

```
imap ^L <Esc>[s1z=`]a
```

`[s` moves to the last spelling mistake
`1z=` chooses the first suggestion
`` `] `` move to the last insert point
`a` append text

Comment: How is this mapping invoked? I tried inputing `^L` in insert mode but it doesn't work.

Comment: Any special reason for using `^L`? Traditionally, spell checking is mapped to `<F10>`. However, `F10` seems to be already in use by gVim, so I eventually settled for the typical `<F7>` Microsoft spell check binding.

Comment: @SergeStroobandt `L` is on home row. Also macs require fn+f10 to get f10 by default, although that can be easily changed.

Comment: To create the `^L` character, you have to hold down the `CTRL` key while hitting the `v` and then `l` key.

Answer (score 42):

An improvement to PDug's answer: To make the spelling correction undoable separately from the insertions, use this:

```
imap <c-l> <c-g>u<Esc>[s1z=`]a<c-g>u
```

`<c-g>u` inserts an undo-break
The rest is the same.

This way, if you don't like the chosen correction, you can undo it using `<Esc>u`. Without the undo-breaks, this would undo the complete insertion. Note that the undo-break at the end of the mapping ensures that text added after the correction can be undone separately from the correction itself.

Also, I found it convenient to map this to <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> (which is easy to reach) in both insert and normal mode like this:

```
imap <c-f> <c-g>u<Esc>[s1z=`]a<c-g>u
nmap <c-f> [s1z=<c-o>
```

This way, you can quickly fix the last error (relative to the cursor).

Answer (score 12):

I can't offer an 'optimal' solution (although I suspect there is a way).

However, you can use <kbd>g</kbd><kbd>i</kbd> to enter insert mode at the place in the file where you last left it. (`help gi` explains this more eloquently).

Comment: Looks like it is the Esc that leaves insert mode. As such, `gi` won't help in this case.

Comment: Ah, sorry about that... I should have tried it before posting. Your map below seems to do the trick anyway (assuming you always need the first suggested spelling).

Comment: I am using `gi` without any problem.

Answer (score 2):

You can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Y</kbd> to accept an element in a popup menu. See `:help complete_CTRL-Y`.

Comment: That puts my cursor in insert mode, but right after the inserted word, not where I was.

Answer (score 2):

I fixed it with the following remap in my `.vimrc`.

```
imap <F2> <Esc>mti<C-X>s<Esc>`tla
```

Press F2 in insert mode to correct the last mistake and go back to insert mode where you were. It overwrites the `t` marker.

Answer (score 1):

I created a plugin just for this use case https://github.com/arecarn/vim-spell-utils

It provides the insert mode mapping CTRL-A that does exactly what was asked and corrects last misspelling with 1st suggestion then returns to insert mode where you you last left off. It also accounts for changes to the line lengths due to spelling corrections while gi and `] do not.

Answer (score 0):

You can press `]s` and `[s` to cycle forward and back misspelled words in a buffer. If you are over a misspelled word in normal mode, you can press `z=` to see a list of spelling suggestions.

answer suggested by [zonker](https://www.linux.com/author/zonker) on [linux.com](https://www.linux.com/training-tutorials/using-spell-checking-vim/)