# VIM: Namespace for markers

Tags: vim

I see that many VIM scripts and shortcuts overwrite markers, such as [this helpful tip](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5313869/343302]). Is there any way to define a namespace for these markers so that they won't collide and won't override markers that the user may be using?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, but this type of action is normally achieved by `:keepjumps` (to prevent automatically updated markers from changing) and using `setpos()`/`getpos()` or `winsaveview()`/`winrestview()`.

Comment: Thank you! I just recently discovered winsaveview() and winrestview().