# Vimscript jump `` when relative position changes

Tags: vim

I have the following alias in my `.vimrc`:

```
inoremap ^Z ^[[s1z=``a
```

This allows me to press `^Z` (`C-z`) in insert mode to jump back to the last misspelled word and correct it to the first suggestion, then jump back to where the cursor was previously and reenter insert mode.

However, this doesn't work when the length of the word changes as a result of the correction. For example, using `[]` to represent the cursor, pressing `C-z` in the context of

```
A grea idea[]
```

will result in

```
A great ide[a]
```

but I want it to result in

```
A great idea[]
```

How can I get this kind of relative jump?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found an older link here on StackOverflow, don't know if it has the same issue, otherwise, I'd live with it: [How to correct vim spelling mistakes quicker?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5312235/how-to-correct-vim-spelling-mistakes-quicker)

```
<Esc>[s1z=`]a
```

[s moves to the last spelling mistake
1z= chooses the first suggestion
`] move to the last insert point
a append text

It also has two more extensive solution that may also work.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, marks aren't adapted for text changes in their line, only for lines added / removed above. But you can avoid this problem by using the `gi` command to re-enter insert mode at the last edited position.

```
inoremap <C-z> <Esc>[s1z=gi
```